# Can you use * in CSS with exceptions?

Tags: css

On this game I play, you can customise your profile layout (it's just  a text-based browser pet-sim game, similar to neopets). Many people choose to hide existing elements to create a blank space to put their own thing (e.g. they hide the site banner, site menu etc). However, to do so, you need to specify every id, and put `display:none`, like so:

```
#id1, #id2, #id3.... etc { 
display: none; 
}
```

I was wondering, is there an easier way to do this? I thought, maybe, try:

```
* { 
display: none; 
}
```

This gave me a completely blank page - perfect, except it also hides my own elements and such.

So, is there a way to perhaps use * but with a few exceptions? Or is there an easier way to select all the ids on the page and hide them?

Comment: Put the universal selector rule first, followed by rules for specific elements you do want to display. To select all elements with ids, use the selector `[id]`.

Comment: @torazaburo that is very helpful, thank you!! I did not know about being able to use [id].